# What usepackage for Subfigure?

Tags: subfig

I am using this

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{chapter4/images/smoothingfruit1.eps} 
            \caption{A full range of typical \textit{fruit puree dataset} spectrum}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothingfruit}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
```

and give me this error:

[image]

I had also added in:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the image that you want to use, not a package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `\begin` should have an `\end`.

The correct code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    % include first image
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{test.jpg} % replace test.jpg with the path of figure of your liking.
    \caption{A full range of typical \textit{fruit puree dataset} spectrum}
    \label{fig:sub-smoothingfruit}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

The output would be like this:

[image]

As you didn't share the document class you are using, the standard article class was assumed. The `subfigure` is used by including `\usepackage{subcaption}` as you have been trying. Your code, however, suffers of two problems:

1. You started `\begin{figure}[h!]`, but you never closed it by `\end{figure}`.
2. You started another `\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}` at the end of your code, never closed as well by `\end{subfigure}`.

You'd better use `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble when adding graphics to your document.